# How to forward data between two ethernet interfaces on a android device(with eth0 and eth1)

Tags: android, router, forwarding

My android device has two independent ethernet interfaces.The eth0 is a physical NIC, and it's in a internal network which ip adrress is 192.168.1.100.  The eth1 comes from a LTE module in a different network which ip address is 10.10.1.10. Now the android device will be used like a router, any datas which come from 192.168.1.* will be forward to 10.10.1.*,  any datas which come from 10.10.1.* also  will be forward to 192.168.1.* by my android device.
How to achieve this function on the android device? Are there any opensoure projects can be used? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted device you can use linux command, for example

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html